# Singleton- python, Situation with the need of only one object

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am having a situation where I have to make sure I only have one object. I am thinking about implementing singleton like following:

```
class One_Of_a_Kind:
    def __init__(self):
        self.do_some_setup()


class One_Creator:
    Only_One = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if One_Creator.Only_One:
            return One_Creator.Only_One
        else:
            One_Creator.Only_One = One_of_a_Kind()
            return One_Creator.Only_One
```

Since I am reading a lot about singleton (pros and cons), I am little hesitant in implementing this code. I would like to know if it is okay and/or considered good practice to use in a situation where only one object of certain class in needed ( or mandatory).

Is there a better way of implementing the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way is the Borg design pattern.  It's very simple to implement in python:

```
class Borg:

    _shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state
```

You don't actually have a single *instance*, but each instance shares the same state - which is the part that matters.

Comment: b1= Borg()  b2 = Borg(), b1==b2 evaluated to False. After you made an edit to your answer, I understood the concept though. Can you please elaborate on why this is better than what I am doing because it still permits creation of multiple instances. Though they share the same state, I would assume that, with each instance, it would use some memory regardless however small.

Comment: Because generally the purpose of singleton design pattern is to share state, not to control memory footprint

Answer (score 2):

When and how to use a singleton is a pretty broad question and primarily opinion based. That being said, I would implement it like this:

```
class Singleton(object):
    state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = Singleton.state
```

The idea is taken from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/). This is sort of a pseudo-singleton, as two instance will not share the same id:

```
>>> s1 = Singleton()
>>> s2 = Singleton()
>>> s1 is s2
False
>>> s1.x = 42
>>> s2.x
42
```